# Audio Manager subdivided into more levels than what Android provides

Tags: java, android, audio

Android provides a default of 15 steps for its sound systems which you can access through Audio Manager. However, I would like to have finer control.

One method of doing so seems to be altering specific files within the Android system to divide the sound levels even further then default. I would like to programmatically achieve the same effect using Java.

Fine volume control is an example of the app being able to divide the sound levels into one hundred distinct intervals. How do I achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Are you writing an app that plays audio, or are you trying to write an audio settings app that affects other apps?

Comment: I am writing an audio settings app that affects all other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, in Java, to get very precise volume adjustment is to access the PCM data directly and multiply it by some factor, usually from 0 up to 1. Another is to try and access the line's volume control, if it has one. I've given up trying to do the latter. The precision is okay in terms of amplitude, but the timing is terrible. One can only have one volume change per audio buffer read.

To access the PCM data directly, one has to iterate through the audio read buffer, translate the bytes into PCM, perform the multiplication then translate back to bytes. But this gives you per-frame control, so very smooth and fast fades can be made.

EDIT: To do this in Java, first check out the sample code snippet at the start of this [java tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html), in particular, the section with the comment

> // Here, do something useful with the audio data that's now in the audioBytes array...

There are several StackOverflow questions that show code for the math to convert audio bytes to PCM and back, using Java. Should not be hard to uncover with a search.

Comment: What Android APIs do you suggest I look into to access the audio buffer and then convert into PCM data? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Android APIs well enough to recommend any. I added a couple sign posts in my reply to appropriate Java solutions, since you originally wrote "I would like to...achieve the same effect in Java."

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but I'm currently trying to solve this issue as well. IF you are making your own media player app and are running an instance of a [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), then you can use the function setVolume(leftScalar, rightScalar) where leftScalar and rightScalar are floats in the range of 0.0 to 1.0. representing logarithmic scale volume for each respective ear.

HOWEVER, this means that you must have a reference to the currently active MediaPlayer instance. If you are making a music app, no biggie. If you're trying to run a background service that allows users to give higher precision over all media output, I'm not sure how to use this in that scenario.

Hope this helps.